# Did Anakin and Ahsoka train at the same time?

Tags: star-wars

This is a question that has been bugging me today, and I can't seem to find any sources that confirm this to be true.

Did Anakin and Ahsoka train at the Jedi Temple on Coruscant at the same time? We know that Anakin is roughly 5 years older than Ahsoka and that he started his Jedi training at the age of 9, which would place Ahsoka at around 4 years old, which is usually when Younglings start their training. That means at some point, they would have both been training as Younglings at the same time in theory. However, in The Clone Wars film, it seems as if the two of them had never met each other before in their lives. That could either mean that Ahsoka started her training late or Anakin's training was accelerated because he was the chosen one and older than the other Younglings and therefore did more practical training through various missions with Obi-Wan. I have another theory that because there might have been a large amount of Younglings at the time, they had to split the classes up, which means they never had the same class together, but surely they would have bumped in to each other at some point.

What's your guys theory on this? Is there any other sources from Legends that confirms they met before the events of The Clone Wars?

Answer (score 7):

Anakin did not train as an Initiate. Upon joining the Jedi Order he was almost immediately apprenticed to Obi-Wan Kenobi and became a Padawan.

He is already wearing a Padawan braid when he appears at the Freedom Day parade on Naboo at the end of *The Phantom Menace*.

[image: The Jedi Path, page 11]

> If I skipped Initiate, can I skip Padawan too? I'm already ready for the trials. -Anakin
>
> <sup>*[The Jedi Path](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book))*, page 11</sup>

Because Anakin skipped Initiate training, he would not have had an opportunity to meet Ashoka Tano before she became his Padawan.

Comment: There are lines in Attack of the Clones that suggest that he trained with Master Yoda in swordfighting. And in the comics we see him in the Jedi temple as a child (not getting along well with the other padawans)

Answer (score 0):

Ahsoka was brought to the temple when she was 3. This was about a year before the events of episode 1.  When Anakin arrived he was made Obi wan's padawan and never trained as a youngling. This is why he didnt meet Ahsoka.This isaso why Yoda was so skeptical about training him. Younglings receive very important training that form their minds. They learn the danger of attachments and emotions. This is something very difficult to instill in an older child as their minds are already molded to the environment they grew up in.

Comment: There are lines in Attack of the Clones that suggest that he trained with Master Yoda in swordfighting. And in the comics we see him in the Jedi temple as a child (not getting along well with the other padawans)